# Function to create a df containing results from another df (sorry for bad phrasing but reproducible example included)

Tags: r, list, function, dataframe

im still a beginner in R so please excuse my bad phrasing. If you have tips how to rephrase im happy to correct this. Anyways, here is the problem:

I have a list with df containing results of differential expression analysis.
Now I would like to create a new df summarising the results with TRUE or FALSE (sig diff or nor in this group).
I found out how to do this by hand but as my list contains 250 dfs, its probably a bad idea to manually create this.

Maybe you can help me to write a function/loop to achieve this goal?
Thanks a lot, I hope the example code does a better job in explaining what I want than my words:

```
#data

goalDF <- data.frame(
  proteins = letters[seq( from = 1, to = 20 )])

firstDF <- data.frame(
  proteins = c('a', 'c', 'd'),
  expression = c(1, 2, 4))


secondDF <- data.frame(
  proteins = c('d', 'e', 'g'),
  expression = c(2, 3, 3))


thirdDF <- data.frame(
  proteins = c('f', 'h', 'a'),
  expression = c(4, 4, 1))


list_with_results <- list(
  first = firstDF,
  second = secondDF,
  third = thirdDF)


#combine

goalDF$first <- goalDF$proteins %in% list_with_results$first$proteins
goalDF$second <- goalDF$proteins %in% list_with_results$second$proteins
goalDF$third <- goalDF$proteins %in% list_with_results$third$proteins
```

Is there a function to automate this? Important would be that the colnames in the goalDF are the same as the df name from the list.
If there is a dplyr/purr solution I would prefer it over a data.table one.

Thanks a bunch!

Sebastian

Comment: Did that solve your challenge @Sebastian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an option using `dplyr` and `purrr`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

goalDF <- data.frame(
  proteins = letters[seq( from = 1, to = 20 )])

firstDF <- data.frame(
  proteins = c('a', 'c', 'd'),
  expression = c(1, 2, 4))


secondDF <- data.frame(
  proteins = c('d', 'e', 'g'),
  expression = c(2, 3, 3))


thirdDF <- data.frame(
  proteins = c('f', 'h', 'a'),
  expression = c(4, 4, 1))


list_with_results <- list(
  first = firstDF,
  second = secondDF,
  third = thirdDF)

purrr::map_dfc(list_with_results, 
               ~ goalDF$proteins %in% .$proteins) %>% 
   cbind(goalDF, .)

#>    proteins first second third
#> 1         a  TRUE  FALSE  TRUE
#> 2         b FALSE  FALSE FALSE
#> 3         c  TRUE  FALSE FALSE
#> 4         d  TRUE   TRUE FALSE
#> 5         e FALSE   TRUE FALSE
#> 6         f FALSE  FALSE  TRUE
#> 7         g FALSE   TRUE FALSE
#> 8         h FALSE  FALSE  TRUE
#> 9         i FALSE  FALSE FALSE
#> 10        j FALSE  FALSE FALSE
#> 11        k FALSE  FALSE FALSE
#> 12        l FALSE  FALSE FALSE
#> 13        m FALSE  FALSE FALSE
#> 14        n FALSE  FALSE FALSE
#> 15        o FALSE  FALSE FALSE
#> 16        p FALSE  FALSE FALSE
#> 17        q FALSE  FALSE FALSE
#> 18        r FALSE  FALSE FALSE
#> 19        s FALSE  FALSE FALSE
#> 20        t FALSE  FALSE FALSE
```